# Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<e> (Upgrading from jQuery 1.6.4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, instanceof

I'm trying to do a drop-in replacement of jQuery 1.6.4 with jQuery 1.11.1; however, I'm taking it version by version. jQuery 1.7.1 works flawlessly, but when I move to jQuery 1.7.2 I start getting this error in the console.

```
Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<e>
```

It appears that `$.data()` returns an element instead of a function and that's what's tripping up the code. Any ideas on how to resolve this conflict, or why the output of `$.data()` is different now.

```
$controls = this.data('_controlClass');   
return $controls instanceof classFn ? $controls : classFn( $controls );
```

In this particular code, $controls returns as a function in jQuery 1.7.1, but as a element in 1.7.2.

## Console Output

```
1.7.1: function jQuerySub( selector, context ) {
            return new jQuerySub.fn.init( selector, context );
        }

1.7.2: [div#buttonToday.ToolbarButton.Button.ButtonBase.Control.BorderBox.NoImage, constructor: function, init: function, className: "ToolbarButton", render: function, content: function…]
```

Comment: I would bite the bullet and upgrade to 1.11

Comment: This issue still exists in 1.11, I'm trying to mitigate the massive amount of issues by jumping so high in version numbers. I can actually get to 1.8.3 before I get other issues. 1.9 removed jQuery.sub() which apparently this code relies on heavily.

Comment: I appreciate the methodical approach - and it's probably better in terms of learning / for interest sake.  I'm just concerned if you do too much to incrementally adhere to an older version, the next increment might blow all your hard work out the water!

Comment: As previously mentioned, the issue still exists in 1.11.1. I took your advice to upgrade, and with the usage of jQuery Migrate, I can still use `jQuery.sub()` until the code is completely rewritten; however, the `jQuery.data()` returning an object instead of a function is still a mystery to me.